# Template function that calls itself results in "instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900"

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I am trying to create a function that accepts a lambda function callback and some `candidate_primes` that can be a `set` or a `vector`, but it gives the error:

> template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900

```cpp
template<class PrimeIter, class Function>
void iter_feasable_primes(
  const PrimeIter& candidate_primes, const uint32_t larger_prime, uint8_t index, Function cb
) {
  std::vector<uint32_t> next_candidate_primes;
  for (const uint32_t p : candidate_primes) {
    // Updates next_candidate_primes
  }
  if (index == 0) {
    // No valid tuples of primes were found
    return;
  }
  for (const uint32_t p : next_candidate_primes) {
    iter_feasable_primes(next_candidate_primes, p, index - 1, [&](std::vector<uint32_t> smaller_primes) {
      smaller_primes.push_back(p);
      cb(smaller_primes);
    });
  }
}
```

I think the problem is the function uses a lambda to call itself, and the compiler doesn't understand the function itself just has a single lambda callback type.

How can I solve this?

I tried to make `index` a template parameter to no avail, as the compiler doesn't seem to understand that it'll never get to `index = -1`, and complains to me that `-1` isn't defined. But ideally I don't want `index` to be a template parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed lambda have unique type and so you have to instantiate infinite recursion.

One way to solve that is to give an unique type, either a custom functor, or a type-erased type as `std::function`

```
template<class PrimeIter>
void iter_feasable_primes(
  const PrimeIter& candidate_primes,
  uint32_t larger_prime,
  uint8_t index,
  std::function<void(std::vector<uint32_t>)> cb)
{
  std::vector<uint32_t> next_candidate_primes;
  for (const uint32_t p : candidate_primes) {
    // Updates next_candidate_primes
  }
  if (index == 0) {
    // No valid tuples of primes were found
    return;
  }
  for (const uint32_t p : next_candidate_primes) {
    iter_feasable_primes(next_candidate_primes, p, index - 1, [&](std::vector<uint32_t> smaller_primes) {
      smaller_primes.push_back(p);
      cb(smaller_primes);
    });
  }
}
```